# How pass the value from a select (populate of object) to an Input

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to pass a value of the selected object office (office.address) to my input. How can I do this?

```
<tr>
    <td>List office: 
        <form:select path="building">
            <form:option value="null"> -- choose office -- </form:option>
                <c:forEach items="${listOffice}" var="office">
                    <form:option value="${office.description}">
                        <c:out value="${office.description}" />
                    </form:option>
                </c:forEach>
        </form:select> 
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td><form:input id="address" path="address" value="" readonly="true"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your full code here so I am assuming that you are aware of **commandName** attribute in form tag to bind the form bean with your page fields.

So now to send the value of select tag to backe nd use path of select as "address" i.e same as it is in your form bean.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but i need to send a value to the input, a value of the parameter of the objeft inside the select.maybe with c:out and c:set but i don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean by input here? Input box?

Comment: Yes, the input box. (<form:input>)